# Can't dynamically fill third column TableLayoutPanel

Tags: vb.net, tablelayoutpanel

Using vb 2012 I am dynamically creating a new table inside a table  and trying to fill 3 columns with labels, 1st and 2nd fill correctly but I can't get filling of third working.

```
Dim ctr As New TableLayoutPanel
ctr.BackgroundImage = Serials_Downloader.My.Resources.Resources.serialbg
ctr.Visible = True
ctr.BackColor = Color.Transparent
ctr.ColumnCount = 3
ctr.Width = 212
ctr.Height = 64

TableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(ctr, 0, TableLayoutPanel1.RowCount - 1)



Dim lblNew2 As New Label()
lblNew2.Text = "a"
lblNew2.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White
lblNew2.Visible = True
lblNew2.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
lblNew2.Font = New Font("Decker", 8)
lblNew2.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
ctr.Controls.Add(lblNew2, 0, 0)

Dim lblNew As New Label()
lblNew.Text = "b"
lblNew.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White
lblNew.Visible = True
lblNew.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
lblNew.Font = New Font("Decker", 8)
lblNew.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
ctr.Controls.Add(lblNew, 1, 0)

Dim lblNew3 As New Label()
lblNew3.Text = "c"
lblNew3.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White
lblNew3.Visible = True
lblNew3.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
lblNew3.Font = New Font("Decker", 8)
lblNew3.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
ctr.Controls.Add(lblNew3, 2, 0)
```

Thanks for help!

EDIT:

Solved,

by changing Labels width to lower value from default "c" appeared.

Comment: could you post complete code?

Comment: this is basically a complete code of this part of the program, i have TableLayoutPanel1 555x204 added in form, it is dling some data from internet and then adding data to the TableLayoutPanel1. (creating new columns and rows). It also creates a new table (ctr) to every cell that is created, with 3 columns containing labels, however, only "a" and "b" is displayed in those tables

Comment: Solved,

by changing Labels width to lower value from default "c" appeared.